# Does javascript has an option to make dots match any character, including line breaks?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I use

```
/a.*b/.test('adadfasdfadfasfaf\n\rafafafaf\r\nb')
```

it returns `false`.

If I want to match line breaks and other characters, which meta character could I use?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `s` modifier, also known as the **dotall** modifier which forces the dot `.` to also match newlines. The dotall modifier **does not** exist in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). The workaround is replacing the dot `.` with...

```
[\S\s]*
```

Answer (score 0):

I sought some data, and found that the `[\s\S]` could match all characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[^]` to match any character, including new line:

#### Example:

```
var s = "test\ning";
var r = s.replace(/s[^]*n/,'X');
```

Check **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ELN7L/)**.

Answer (score -1):

I just realized you are talking about JavaScript explicitly... where the dotall modifier doesn't exist. Like you already found out, you can use `[\s\S]` to work around this problem.

---

For RegEx in general, you use the *dotall* modifier **s**:

```
/foo.bar/s
```

This lets `.` match everything, even newlines.

Comment: But in javascript RegExp engine, there is no flags s let it be.

Comment: I missed that you are talking about JavaScript at first, you already found the answer yourself ;)

Comment: Nowadays JavaScript has the s modifier (/s flag) and this syntax works, matching also the newlines.

Answer (score -2):

You can match line feeds and carriage return with `[\r\n]`:

`a(:?[\r\n]|.)*b`

---

Whoever decided to downvote my "unhelpful" post has clearly not done **any testing whatsoever**:

See this link, which shows my regex working:
http://jsfiddle.net/cetanu/p6P7p

and here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/C5I6PO1TJqUQcTgG